# Estimation of two successive treatments - Differences in Differences

Tags: panel-data, difference-in-difference, trend, treatment-effect

I am trying to estimate the effect of **two successives policies** on individual subjects.

I have a panel data following individuals each 3 years from 2005 : 2005, 2008, 2011, 2014 and 2017.

The *first treatment (T1)* occured in 2014 : individuals could choose to enter in a program.

The *second treatment (T2)* replaced the first treatment in 2017 (the program's setting changed a little bit but the objectives of the program and eligible individuals are similar to T1) : individuals still have the choice to enter in the program or not.

Then, I have potentially 3 treatment groups vs one control group :
Treated group 1 : T1=1 and T2=1 
Treated group 2 : T1=0 and T2=1 
Treated group 3 : T1=1 and T2=0 
Control group : T1=0 and T2=0 
Note that most of people who took T1 chose to take T2.

First, I estimate the first treatment using combined group 1 and group 3 vs control group, in a DiD framework with fixed effect and matching, ignoring the second treatment period (excluding year 2017 from my analysis).

But I was wondering how to implement the second treatment in one DiD analysis to estimate separately the policies and potentially say something about the cumulative effect of them (group 1)?
How can I justify the parallel trend assumption for each group, knowing that I don't have a period between my two treatments?

Or am I restricted to do separate regressions for each group vs control group and have different pre-treatment period for each group (i.e. for group 1 : pre-treatment period is 2005-2011 and for group 2, it is 2005-2014)?

Thanks for reading and future answers !

Aimee

Comment: Welcome. So the onset of the second treatment occurs while the first is already in place? And, if my reading is correct, a person can be in either one of the two treatment conditions, or both?

Comment: Thanks for asking. The second treatment replaced the first treatment i.e. when the second treatment started, the first treatment stopped. In what I called "treated group 1", a person chose to enter in the first program (T1=0 in 2014). When the government stopped the first treatment (in 2017), they propose a second treatment to replace the first and the person could choose to enter in the second program too. In "treated group 2", a person didn't choose to enter in the first program (T1=0) but three years later, when a new program/treatment is proposed, she chose to enter in the program (T2=0).